# Реакция приложения на изменение состояния звонка

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-studio

Приложение вылетает с ошибкой. IDE Android Studio указывает на строку с ошибкой: `telephonyManager.listen(new TelListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);`

вот часть кода MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephonyManager.listen(new TelListener(), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    }
 private class TelListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    break;
                default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

В манифесте права прописал:`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_FONE_STATE"/>`
Непойму в чём проблема.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

попробуйте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

вместо

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_FONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо, мне стыдно за мой вопрос. Искал проблему в коде, а оказалось опечатка...